# Thymeleaf default fragment in case reslution fails

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a fragment which is evaluated from a field value

```
<div data-th-replace="fragments/${obj.fooType} :: ${obj.fooType}( fieldPrefix='obj.bars[__${barStat.index}__]')"></div>
```

This works well and good when an appropriate fragment html exists for a variable value, however I want to define a default fragment which would be evaluated in case thymeleaf fails to find a fragment with that particular name **for that particular section only**.

Is something like that achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They answered this question in [this issue](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/529). The answer is to use the Elvis operator like this:

```
<div th:insert="~{mytemplate :: myfragment} ?: ~{}">...</div>
```